# How to put a sprite behind other sprites in pygame?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I want to put a sprite on screen, but I want it in the back layer behind other sprites, so that it does not cover up those sprites when they pass by each other.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just blit the `Surface`/`Sprite` that should go to the background before the other `Surface`/`Sprite` that should go to the foreground.

If you use the `Sprite` class, you could also use the [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) or [`LayeredDirty`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredDirty) groups to handle this for you by using a `layer` attribute or kwarg when adding the `Sprite` to the group.